# Copy sharepoint Production/live 2010 to Test server

Tags: sharepoint-online, development-enviroment

I want to copy our live production environment over to Test server, can someone please suggest the easiest and painless way to do this. I don't want the documents/files etc copied across as there is way too many.

Comment: Your tag is SharePoint Online? do you want from online to on prem or what?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think a copy without files is a easy or painless endeavor.  I routinely copy portions of my farm from prod to test.  Assuming you are starting from scratch in test:

1. Create Farm

   A. For less pain, use the same service accounts.  For more security, use new ones
2. Manually stand up same services
3. Make backups of all content databases (this is the guts)
4. Restore databases to test

   A. Don't forget to change permissions if you opted for more security in 1.A.
5. Create webapps mirroring prod with temp databases
6. Create mirrored site collections in temp databases
7. Deploy .wsp customizations mirroring prod
8. Detatch temp databases and attach databases restored in step 4
9. $$$

At least that is how I've done it.  Someone else may have a simpler way.

Comment: Hiya, Thank you for your response. Would I still need to create a farm if there is already a older version of sharepoint 2010 on the Test server? Also can I use the Back up and restore option on central admin to copy prod to test?

Comment: No, just ensure the same services are running and build mirroring webapps.  Google says that restoring a backup from CA doesn't work.